# How are you supposed to update a texture per frame in Vulkan?

Tags: 2d, game-engine, vulkan, texture2d

I'm trying to work with 2D in vulkan along with 3D. So right now testing out updating a texture for every frame as whatever 2D is going on. I've gotten something of a texture updater working, the problem is that it's very slow and probably not the way it's supposed to be done. Is there any better way of getting this done? The code is based on the https://vulkan-tutorial.com/ code.

https://vulkan-tutorial.com/code/26_depth_buffering.cpp

```
    void UpdateTexture()
{
    vkDeviceWaitIdle(device);
    vkFreeMemory(device, textureImageMemory, nullptr);

    VkBuffer stagingBuffer;
    VkDeviceMemory stagingBufferMemory;
    createBuffer(imageSize, VK_BUFFER_USAGE_TRANSFER_SRC_BIT, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT, stagingBuffer, stagingBufferMemory);

    void* data;
    vkMapMemory(device, stagingBufferMemory, 0, imageSize, 0, &data);
    memcpy(data, pixel2.data(), static_cast<size_t>(imageSize));
    vkUnmapMemory(device, stagingBufferMemory);

    createImage(texWidth, texHeight, VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_SRGB, VK_IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL, VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT | VK_IMAGE_USAGE_SAMPLED_BIT, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT, textureImage, textureImageMemory);

    transitionImageLayout(textureImage, VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_SRGB, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL);
    copyBufferToImage(stagingBuffer, textureImage, static_cast<uint32_t>(texWidth), static_cast<uint32_t>(texHeight));
    transitionImageLayout(textureImage, VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_SRGB, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL);

    vkDestroyBuffer(device, stagingBuffer, nullptr);
    vkFreeMemory(device, stagingBufferMemory, nullptr);

    createTextureImageView();
    createDescriptorPool();
    createDescriptorSets();
    createCommandBuffers();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This code looks like a direct translation of some OpenGL code, and not particularly good/modern OpenGL code at that.

There's a *lot* wrong in this code, but most of it boils down to over-synchronization.

First, you should always view any call to `vkDeviceWaitIdle` as the wrong thing to do. The only exception would be when you are preparing to destroy the `VkDevice` itself. There is no other reason to do a full CPU/GPU sync like that.

Presumably, this synchronization exists so that you can be sure the GPU is finished using the image before modifying it. This is the wrong thing to do. You should instead employ multiple-buffering. That is, you should have *two* images that you use. One is currently being used in a rendering process, while the other is being transferred into.

Instead of doing a full device sync, you instead synchronize with the batch you sent two frames ago. That is, if you're wanting to transfer data for use by frame 10, then you must first do a fence-sync operation with the batch you sent in frame 8. Frame 9 is still being processed, but frame 8 is probably done by now. So the synchronization shouldn't hurt too much.

Second, never allocate memory in the middle of an operation like this. Memory gets allocated early in your application, and you leave it allocated until it's time to destroy your application. If you need a staging buffer, then keep it around and reuse it in subsequent frames. Make sure to allocate sufficient storage up-front.

Whatever your `createBuffer` call is doing, it seems very much like a bad idea. Vulkan is not OpenGL; Vulkan separated memory from buffers/textures that use it for a reason. Creating APIs that hide this separation basically throws all of that away.

Similarly, never unmap memory, unless you're about to destroy that memory object. There's no problem in Vulkan ([or OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Object#Persistent_mapping)) with leaving a piece of memory mapped indefinitely. Just map the entire memory's range and leave it mapped. Indeed, you could just pass the mapped pointer directly to your image loader, depending on how the memory get written by the image loading code (if it tries to read data from this pointer, they could be trouble).

Lastly, the commands doing the transfer need to be synchronized with the commands that consume the image. How this happens depends on which queues are being used to do the transfer.

And of course, if you want optimal performance, you may want to check to see if your implementation can read from linear images in your shader. If it can, then you may not need staging at all; you can just write the data directly to the memory in Vulkan's image format, and use it directly.

Employing all of the above is going to add a lot of complexity to your application. But that's how it's supposed to work.

Comment: Absolutely agree with everything here, but would just add that the OP should also review whether he really needs to transfer data from the CPU to a texture in the first place. No information is provided about why he's got 2D data that needs to be transfered from CPU to GPU every frame, but there's a fair chance that it would be possible to generate the 2D data on the GPU using draw calls on a render-to-texture. If it's a viable option for the use case, then it's likely to be the most efficient option.

Comment: Right now I'm thinking of using a huge map texture then copying portion of the map to the screen texture for starting off testing. But I'll probably use something like  a couple background layers(Textures), a couple of sprite layers, maybe foreground layer if need. Then use the shaders to put them together into the screen image. The thing is that I'll need to update the layers per frame, because of animation, camera movement, any other stuff I'm not not thinking of for the base example.

Comment: Can you design it in a way where you are updating metadata per frame, not the textures themselves? And how huge is "huge"?

Comment: @solidpixel: What do you mean by "metadata"? If this data is part of the image view, then you can create new views every frame (though you probably shouldn't).

Comment: @solidpixel Frame Size would be 4k. I found something about about texture atlases for sprite. I might be about to use that for the map it's self too.  I think I"m going take a look in that direction.

https://snorristurluson.github.io/TextureAtlas/
https://snorristurluson.github.io/TextureAtlas/

Comment: @NicolBolas Metadata = anything other than bulk texel color data upload.

Comment: near the last paragraph ``` you may want to check to see if your implementation can read from linear images in your shader. If it can, then you may not need staging at all;``` how to check this, what to check specifically? @NicolBolas

Comment: @May: In order to use any image in any way, you must first ask the implementation if you are allowed to use an image created with those parameters in one of those ways. This is what `vkGetPhysicalDeviceImageFormatProperties` is for.

Comment: @NicolBolas i searched a bit , it seems a buffer like this is called ```texel buffer```, is that the correct one?

Comment: @May: We're talking about images, not buffers. And when I say "linear image", I mean *precisely* that: an *image* that uses *linear* tiling.

Comment: @NicolBolas you mean ```VkImageTiling tiling;``` in the VkImageCreateInfo right?, but how do you write to this memory without a staging buffer? I can only think of ```VkCmdCopyBuffertoImage()```, is there anything like ```VkCmdCopyRawDataToImage (made-up function , not in vulkan)```

Comment: @May: The whole point of this endeavor is that you *don't do a copy*. So obviously the memory you're putting your pixel data into is *mapped*. That's why you have to check that the implementation allows you to use linear tiled images as a texture and that one of the memory types supported for this purpose is also host-visible.

Answer (score 0):

A naive way consists in using the CPU to define the update depending on the time or data and then update the data for the shader, such as a MVP transformation matrix. But this is inefficient with lots of syncing and too low refresh rates, and also overloading the cpu in a loop.

So people recommend using many buffers sometimes mentioning old drivers. If someone can clarify it, that would be nice. I have a naive and probably wrong guess. If they know exactly the frame rate, then they can calculate the time for each frame and dispatch several frames in advance. But it confuses me because the frame rate is dynamic, especially for new screens with the FreeSync functionality that have dynamic refresh rates.

I have thought of a third possibility. One can use the clock directly in the shader. GL_EXT_shader_realtime_clock provides clockRealtimeEXT. It has no defined unit, and will wrap when exceeding the maximum value. But it is said "globally coherent by all invocations on the GPU". During initialization, you can measure its rate using a uniform buffer, and then assume the rate will be constant. And also manage the wrapping.

Then if you can write your shaders as a function of time, for example in a translation, that would be efficient. You just need the initial data. Remember that one must avoid if conditions in shaders.